# javascript: deleting cookie not working as expected

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
delete_cookie("intro");
var intro = readCookie("intro");
alert(intro);

function readCookie(name) 
{
    var nameEQ = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return decodeURIComponent(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
    }
    return null;
}

function delete_cookie( name ) 
{
  document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

For some reason, it is not working. When reading the cookie it still returns 1.
Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: @Jesse no need to say you've answered, OP will get a notification, commenting that is just noise

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You should define path on which cookie exists to ensure that you delete the real one

Try using

```
function delete_cookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including the domain like so: `document.cookie = name + "=; path=/; domain=.MYDOMAIN"; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;";`

I had the same problem some time ago, and for some reason it seemed to be trying to access the cookie on the wrong domain. Also make sure when you set the cookie, to use the same exact domain.